# Regex to match exact word in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I've looked around but haven't been able to find a working solution to my problem.

I have an array of two strings `input` and want to test which element of the array contains an exact substring `Test`.

One thing I have tried (among numerous other attempts):

```
input = ["Test's string", "Test string"]
# Alternative input array that it needs to work on:
#  ["Testing string", "some Test string"]
substring = "Test"
if (input[0].match(/\b#{substring}\b/))
  puts "Test 0 "
  # Do something...
elsif (input[1].match(/\b#{substring}\b/))
  puts "Test 1"
  # Do something different...
end
```

The desired result is a print of `"Test 1"`.  The input can be more complex but overall I am looking for a way to find an exact match of a substring in a longer string.
I feel like this should be a rather trivial regex but I haven't been able to come up with the correct pattern. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @nhahtdh if you have a better solution I'm open to it. My actual case is more complex then I made it appear to be here. I attempted to simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov Unfortunately that won't work as my case is a little more complex. For example, `input[1]` can contain more than just the single word `Test`

Comment: Then could you provide this complex case? No matter how much words `input[1]` contains as long as you are looking for exact strings correspondence

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read your example - I thought you want to search for substring, while you want search for word. Regex should be the simpler solution in term of the amount of code to write.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I edited the question slightly to try and clear up confusion. In reality, I am looking for a word in a longer string, and I need it to match exactly.

Comment: Your pattern is correct then and since your code is working, you probably want to ask for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It seems to work in some cases but not in others. I admit, I never executed the code exactly as written. In one of my cases, the `input[0]` string contains something similar to `Test's` which will yield a false positive and send me into "Test 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code may be what you are looking for.

```
input = ["Testing string", "Test string"]
substring = "Test"

if (input[0].match(/[^|\s]#{substring}[\s|$]/)
  puts "Test 0 "
elsif (input[1].match(/[^|\s]#{substring}[\s|$]/)
  puts "Test 1"
end
```

The meaning of the pattern /[^|\s]#{substring}[\s|$]/ is

1. [^|\s] : left side of the substring is begining of string(^) or white space,
2. ## {substring} : subsring is matched exactly,
3. [\s|$] : right side of the substring is white space or end of string($).

Comment: I changed my question according to the change of your question.

Comment: This didn't exactly solve my problem but it put me on the write track to generating my pattern. Thanks!

Comment: jkeuhlen, you should learn the way to express what is your problem!

Comment: Yeah I realize that this wasn't very clear. I oversimplified what my actual problem was and I didn't phrase my question correctly at all. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

One way to that is as follows:

```
input = ["Testing string", "Test"]

"Test #{ input.index { |s| s[/\bTest\b/] } }"
  #=> "Test 1"

input = ["Test", "Testing string"]
"Test #{ input.index { |s| s[/\bTest\b/] } }"
  #=> "Test 0"
```

`\b` is the regex denotes a word boundary.

Maybe you want a method to return the index of the first element of `input` that contains the word?  That could be:

```
def matching_index(input, word)
  input.index { |s| s[/\b#{word}\b/i] }
end

input = ["Testing string", "Test"]   
matching_index(input, "Test")    #=> 1
matching_index(input, "test")    #=> 1
matching_index(input, "Testing") #=> 0
matching_index(input, "Testy")   #=> nil
```

Then you could use it like this, for example:

```
word = 'Test'
puts "The matching element for '#{word}' is at index #{ matching_index(input, word) }"
  #=> The matching element for 'Test' is at index 1

word = "Testing"
puts "The matching element for '#{word}' is '#{ input[matching_index(input, word)] }'"
  #The matching element for 'Testing' is 'Testing string'
```

Comment: Sorry I guess my question wasn't quite as clear as I thought. I don't want to ONLY print out "Test 0" or "Test 1" I want to actually do things in each of those cases. I wrote it that way to just simplify my condition.

Comment: I guess you need to clarify then. "The desired result is a print of "Test 1" seems pretty clear.  @AvinashRaj, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Edited the question some. I had hoped the prints weren't seen as the end goal of my code but I guess I was mistaken!

Comment: Again, I'm not looking for an index. I need to check for occurrences of a substring within a larger string and then execute code in one or another conditional statement.

Comment: Yes, but if you have the index `i`, the element (string) of `input` containing the word is `input[i]`. Right?  If you just want the string, rather than the index, then `input.find { |s| s[/\b#{word}\b/i] }` does it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your bounding.  In your original question, the word Test will match the first string because the ' is will match the \b word boundary.  It's a perfect match and is responding with "Test 0" correctly.  You need to determine how you'll terminate your search.  If your input contains special characters, I don't think the regex will work properly. /\bTest my $money.*/ will never match because the of the $ in your substring.

What happens if you have multiple matches in your input array?  Do you want to do something to all of them or just the first one?